# SSL certification apache

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I want to setup https on my site

> ```
> <VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
>   ...
>   SSLEngine on
>
>   SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/www.blabla.com/public.crt
>   SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/www.blabla.com/private.key
>   SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/www.blabla.com/intermediate.crt
>   ...
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

I've bought certificate and they provide me: ssl certificate code, root certificate code and intermediate certificate code. What is CertificateFile and CertificateKeyFile from these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SSLCertificateKeyFile would have been passed in as the key when you created the request -- it doesn't come from the CA.
- SSLCertificateFile is the "ssl certificate code" you got from the CA
- SSLCAcertificate file is the "root certificate code" you got from the CA
- The "intermediate certificate code" from the CA should be identified by SSLCertificateChainFile